# Chessboard-Image Processing frame difference

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, chess

I want to perform image difference between these two pictures and result should be only that chessboard square block(In this case only white queen's) where there is a difference from the 1st image.So that my machine learning model will predict that piece present on that block.How to do this in python?
Thanks in advance[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDkKW.jpg)

[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrufH.jpg)

Comment: The two images are not properly aligned. To get the image subtraction work, the camera shall not move for better results. It would be great if you can fix the location of camera, else it would get a bit complex, as you will have to detect the chess board first and then align them using `cv2.wrapPerspective` before subtracting the images to get the difference.

Comment: @ZdaR If I fix the camera then how to crop only that specific square after taking image difference,is there any way for that?

Comment: @ZdaR please refer Creating Training Images part in this document-http://www.chuckorde.com/chess-vision-dnn-2.html .Is there any idea to loop through board and do like this?Thanks for your time....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chess-Image difference between two frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59917159/chess-image-difference-between-two-frames)

Comment: @beaker Not yet